# aria2 Unrecognized URI or unsupported protocol When the url have space in it

Tags: aria2

My input:

```
http://www.example.com/New file.zip
```

When try to download a remote file that have space in its url aria2 complains about it:

```
Exception caught
Exception: [download_helper.cc:451] errorCode=1 Unrecognized URI or unsupported protocol: New
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the space into "%20"

`aria2c http://www.example.com/New%20file.zip`

Or

`aria2c "http://www.example.com/New file.zip"`

Comment: If using environment variables, this works as well: 
`aria2c ""${download_url}"`